# Missing Artifact error in MAVEN in geoserver

Tags: java, maven, geoserver, artifact

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd ">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>hello_wps</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>8-ENTERPRISE-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>hello_wps</name>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
      <version>8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>main</artifactId>
       <version>8-ENTERPRISE-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <classifier>tests</classifier>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>


<dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.1</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.mockrunner</groupId>
       <artifactId>mockrunner</artifactId>
       <version>0.3.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <source>1.5</source>
           <target>1.5</target>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>

   <repositories>
     <repository>
       <id>opengeo</id>
       <name>opengeo</name>
       <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
     </repository>
   </repositories>

</project>
```

i'm new to maven and geoserver as well. was just trying basic installation of geoserver and found the error in `POM.XML` file of maven project. Error is shown in two `<dependency>` tabs which are exactly 1st and 2nd after `<dependencies>` tab.

Errors :

```
Missing artifact org.geotools:gt-process:jar:8-SNAPSHOT

Missing artifact org.geoserver:main:jar:tests:8-ENTERPRISE-SNAPSHOT
```

Thanks for the solution in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the quick start docs for geotools:
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/maven.html

step 7 "under Creating a new project"

> If you are using a nightly build (such as 14-SNAPSHOT) and add a
>   reference to the snapshot repository.
>
> ```
> <repositories>
>     <repository>
>       <snapshots>
>         <enabled>true</enabled>
>       </snapshots>
>       <id>boundless</id>
>       <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
>       <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
>     </repository>
> </repositories>
> ```

I have taken a quick look at the versions available in this repository and to use it, you will need to change your maven co-ordinates to something like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
  <version>10-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>main</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.8</version>
   <classifier>tests</classifier>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

as the original versions you are after are not present.

Comment: Thanks sir. It helps me to solve the error. Now i stuck with an anothor error.
I'm preferring this link to implement WPS process. [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html)
I got an error in 2nd step of "Create the Process Class".

Comment: Could you mark my answer please? You probably want to raise another question for the new problem.